# Prevent reserved words being used for Column Names in Oracle 12c via a trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

Is there a way to prevent Oracle from permitting reserved words in column names via a trigger? This solution (after I fix the Declare typo) has compilation errors and doesn't work. I want to ensure reserved words are never used, even if quoted. [System-level way to enforce that reserved words may not be used for Oracle column names?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221352/system-level-way-to-enforce-that-reserved-words-may-not-be-used-for-oracle-colum)

Comment: I would think that the best way to do that would be through the code review process and good documentation on how to write code and name things. You could end up creating more problems then you solve.

Comment: Agree with @Gandolf989. Also avoid the use of ORMs whenever possible!

Comment: The reason for this is to catch mistakes. There is a naming standard that prohibits these words but to prevent issues happening in the first place we would like this safety net.